# Remove x-webkit-speech selectively from chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

Is there a way to remove the speech input from a few selective input fields. I do not want to turn it off on the whole but i want to remove it for a few fields for which I did not give the specific attribute x-webkit-speech.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you didn't put `x-webkit-speech` on a field, how did it get speech input in the first place?

Comment: It seems to be enabled by default. I don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has this problem and I thought it was a Google Chrome update, but upon further investigation I discovered an extension I installed was automatically adding `x-webkit-speech` to my inputs (on all sites I visited)

**Try disabling some of your extensions (or all of them).**

The one that did it for me was: [SpeakIt!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speakit/pgeolalilifpodheeocdmbhehgnkkbak)